# How do I download Elementary OS for free?

Tags: elementary-website, download

I go to the [Elementary OS page](https://elementary.io/) and it forces me to donate before I can download.

How do I download it free to try out?

*Yes and No it's not a duplicate. There is problem with the way the other question is asked. The very first time a person goes to this webpage will not be thinking they need to 're download it for free'. So, it's unlikely they will find the answer via an intuitive search. My question actual gets right to the point, which makes it more likely they will find the solution. Perhaps the best thing would be to add a button to allow a free download so people are not confused in the first place. But until then, my question will most likely turn up for someone with this issue vs. the other question. I believe it makes the forum cleaner and more helpful.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the button "Custom" write 0 then click "Purchase elementary OS", then "Download". The download will start without problem and without asking you any money!

It would be great to download it via bitorrent and seed for awhile, since you're not paying.